# Input ID in Shiny selectInput() not refreshing the results

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to provide Organization name as input in ui.R as following -

```
selectInput("Organization", "Enter an Org:", choices = c("Blenheim Palace", "Chatsworth", "Gloucester Cathedral", "Manchester Cathedral", "Royal Albert Hall", "StPauls Cathedral"))
```

I try to use this input to refresh my wordcloud. Essentially when I select an organization, say Blenheim Palace, wordcloud should change with the comments for that organization from tripadvisor.com.
My `server.R` code is as following -

```
OrganizationInput <- reactive({switch(input$Organization, "Blenheim Palace" = Blenheim_Palace, "Chatsworth" = Chatsworth, "Gloucester Cathedral" = Gloucester_Cathedral, "Manchester Cathedral" = Manchester_Cathedral, "Royal Albert Hall" = Royal_Albert_Hall, "StPauls Cathedral" = StPauls_Cathedral)}) 

rawData <- reactive(function(){
    some_txt <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'SELECT REVIEW_COMMENTS FROM XXXXXX.tripadvisor_data where brand_name = "OrganizationInput()"')
    some_txt <- data.frame(some_txt)
```

I try to use `rawData()` as input for wordcloud. But I get following error - 
`Error: invalid 'cex' value`, if I give individual names (say Blenheim Palace) in rawData, it works. 
Any help/clarification will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `OrganizationInput` to be a character string, do you need to enquote the values in switch a la:

```
OrganizationInput <- reactive({switch(input$Organization, "Blenheim Palace" = "Blenheim_Palace", "Chatsworth" = "Chatsworth", ...
```

Otherwise, you're trying to reference a variable named named `Blenheim_Palace`, which likely doesn't exist, right?

Answer (score 1):

It was essentially a problem of parametrizing input$Organization in sqlQuery(). I used the idea from

[R Shiny error 'closure' not subsettable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264306/r-shiny-error-closure-not-subsettable)

and it worked. thanks for looking into my question.